# Do beef foreshank (the shin) and hindshank taste different? Should they be cooked differently?

Tags: beef, cut-of-meat

What are the practical differences between the foreshank and hindshank? In terms of the amount of fat they contain, dryness, sinewiness and taste. Should they be cooked slightly differently? Does one need a longer cooking time than the other?

Answer (score 1):

The fore and hindshank are very similar in characteristics. The hind can be a little tougher as the hind does a bit more work, so a bit longer cooking time. They have a similar taste and texture.